# What is the name of the frontal part of the neck?

Tags: word-request

Neck is the part which connect the head to the body. I would like to know what is the name of the frontal part of the neck - in English?

[image: She's touching her frontal neck]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [throat](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/throat):

> 1) the front part of the neck

Comment: Thank you. I always knew the 2nd meaning (in the link that you put) of the throat, I've never new about the 1st meaning. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The crook of the neck. It's where the neck meets the shoulder on the front, the opposite of the nape of the neck.